# Why is shortcuts map empty?

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to use the [`MenuBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuBar-class.html) widget with shortcuts enabled using the example implementation provided at the beginning of this API documentation (including `MenuEntry`).

I've provided a map with at least one shortcut.

I'm getting this:

> Cannot register an empty map of shortcuts

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
        LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyB): Intent.doNothing,
      },
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'App Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

The above error in call stack comes from this line:

```dart
_shortcutsEntry = ShortcutRegistry.of(context).addAll(MenuEntry.shortcuts(result));
```

However, note that this line comes from `State<MyHomePage>`, `_MyHomePageState`.

I'm using GetX, but it doesn't matter: I've tried `MaterialApp` instead of `GetMaterialApp` and the same error occurs.

---

I've also encapsulated the home into a `Shortcuts` and same result:

```dart
Shortcuts(
  shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyB): Intent.doNothing,
  },
  child: const MyHomePage(title: 'App Home Page'),
)
```